free() on result of placement new?
I'm trying to understand whether it's valid to call free() on the result of placement new in a buffer allocated by malloc().
Consider the following. Does this code exhibit any undefined behavior?
(Assume that T does not overload any new or delete operators)
T* create() {
    void* buf = malloc(sizeof(T) + 10);
    T* obj = new(buf) T;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    T* obj = create();
    obj->~T();
    free(obj); // or free(static_cast<void*>(obj)
}

Can the pointer returned by placement new on a malloc()'ed buffer then be passed to free()? This should be well-defined if we can guarantee that static_cast<void*>(obj) == buf, but I'm not sure if that equality is actually guaranteed; the placement new operator returns its argument unchanged, but I'm not sure if we're allowed to assume that the placement new expression returns a pointer with the same value/to the same address.
If this isn't defined, is there any other way to get a pointer that can be used to both access the object and free it, without encountering undefined behavior?

typically things that come with a create function will also come with a destroy function that knows how to handle cleaning up the memory.  In those cases you can wrap the destroy call into the deleter of a unique_ptr.

Ignoring the straight-up errors in this code, I don't think this is safe because malloc might not return a pointer that meets the alignment requirements of T.

@paddy: Unless memory fails me to an unusual degree today, malloc returns a pointer suitably aligned fro any type.

According to §17.6.3.4 placement new will return the original pointer. OTOH, §6.7.6.1 imposes alignment requirement which malloc may violate. §20.2.12 does say that malloc "return a pointer to a suitable created object" but I don't understand what that means... malloc(3) says that malloc "return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any type". So, the answer appears to be yes. :)

free() does not call the destructor. If you use placement new, you should also call the destructor before freeing the memory.

@Dúthomhas: This code does that, doesn't it?

@NateEldredge yes, obj->~T(); calls the destructor

Whatever problem this is supposed to solve, ask about that, because there has to be a better, safer way.  Looks like an X-Y problem.

std::malloc is supposed to return a pointer with alignas(std::max_align_t) attribute. So the resultant pointer is suitable for most usecases(minus over-aligned types). The real problem is that std::malloc may return nullptr on failure. So, placement and explicit destruction must be guarded against nullptr(an if statement is required).

@JerryCoffin here is a simple test showing malloc returning 16-byte aligned memory for an allocation of 32 + 10 bytes, emulating a scenario where T requires 32-byte alignment, but the addition of 10 bytes causes it to be incorrectly aligned. It is reasonable to expect that malloc returns memory with appropriate alignment for the size passed in, but that doesn't extend to adding arbitrary amounts that fool it into thinking it's reserving storage for an object with lesser alignment requirements.

@paddy: "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)." (N1256, $7.20.3/1). If your test shows it failing to meet that requirement, then what you're seeing is a bug in the implementation, not a characteristic of malloc as defined.

@paddy -- you have a bug in your test, you should have used size_t maxalign = alignof(std::max_align_t); not the sizeof(std::max_align_t)

If you use placement new, you are giving responsibility of memory management to the caller.  It is simply a means of calling the constructor to instantiate an object in caller defined memory.
To that end it is not for placement-new to define how the memory you provide is either acquired or disposed of.  What does define that is your use of malloc() and in that sense, of course you should use free().
That said, in this case you are simply duplicating what the default new would do in any event, more safely and succinctly.  Certainly the code example cannot be recommended - it requires the caller of create to know that placement new was used and and that the memory was allocated by malloc.  It would be better for the allocation to be performed by the caller so that it was symmetric.

Thank you for the response. The reason for the weird allocation method is that T is actually some struct of the form {size_t dataLength; unsigned char data[1]; } , and the intent is to allocate extra space for the data, which new and delete can't do. There's a better solution overriding new and delete for T to create a placement version that allocates extra space, but I'm trying to make minimal changes to the code just to remove some currently-existing UB (our current implementation is using mismatched new and delete)


Does this code exhibit any undefined behavior?

For most types, it does not.
It is possible that T is an over-aligned type (e.g. alignas(1024)), in which case std::malloc may return an insufficiently aligned pointer.
You would have to call aligned_alloc in that case, which can be used with free.
That should be the only problem.
As explained in [expr.new] p20, new(buf) T; is translated into a call to operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr), which has has the following result:

Returns: ptr.

I couldn't actually find a strict guarantee that the result of operator new represents the same address as that of the new-expression.
In fact, it's said that this may not be the case for arrays of std::byte, char, and unsigned char (see [expr.new] p17).
However, for placement new, the amount of space requested is exactly sizeof(T), so it would never be safe for the implementation to create the object anywhere but at the result of operator new.
This was clarified and accepted as a defect report in CWG Issue 2382.
Therefore, buf can be passed to free just as well as obj. Conversion from void* to T* and back are not allowed to change the address that the pointer represents.
However, if you really need dynamic allocation to use malloc and free, you could also

replace operator new and operator delete (see How to properly replace global new & delete operators), or
write a custom allocator that uses malloc (see malloc/free based STL allocator).


std::aligned_alloc cannot be used on MSVC. MS CRT provides _aligned_malloc+_aligned_free instead.

(Putting down my comment as an answer.)
There are two possible gotchas that I can see:

Does T* obj = new(buf) T return the original pointer? According to §17.6.3.4 it does:

[[nodiscard]] void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
Returns: ptr.


Does the pointer returned by malloc satisfy alignment requirements? Specifically, §6.7.6 states that:

Object types have alignment requirements ... which place restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated. ... Attempting to create an object ... in storage that does not meet the alignment requirements of the object's type is undefined behavior.

C++ standard as regards to malloc is a bit murky (see §20.2.12):

These functions implicitly create objects ... in the returned region of storage and return a pointer to a suitable created object.

However, §7.24.3 of the C standard is a bit more clear:

The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and size less than or equal to the size requested.

And, the POSIX man page for malloc(3p) confirms that.


So, unless your type T is over-aligned (ie, uses alignas specifier), the answer to your question:

Does this code exhibit any undefined behavior?

is no.

should the std::launder be used to be safe?
